# start and stop/reset a timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

so i'm trying to make a function where you click a button and a box turns red and counts down from 300 then changed back to green, i had that all working but if you clicked the button again it would count down faster and faster so i wanted to make it change the button to stop so you could click it again and have it basically reset so you didnt have to wait out the timer, right now i have this but it wont work

```
function alttimer(timernum){
if($(alt1but).val() == "Start") //button is start
    {
        $(alt1color).attr("src", "red.png");
        alttimer1();
        $(alt1but).val("Stop");
    }
    else //button is stop
    {
        $(alt1but).val("Start");
        clearTimeout(alttimer2);
        $(alt1color).attr("src", "green.png");
        t1 = '300';
        $('#alt1tim').attr("value", "");
    }
};

var alttimer1;
alttimer1 = setTimeout("function(){
            if(t1 == '0')
            {
                $(alt1color).attr('src', 'green.png');
                name = $('#alt1t').val();
                $('#alt21im').attr('value', '');
                t1 = '300';
            }
            else
            {
                $('#alt1tim').attr('value', t1);
                t1--;
            }

};",1000);
```

Comment: why is your function is string?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of weird what you're doing. I totally recommend you to do a different thing:

```
var counter = 300;
var active = false;
var intervalId = -1;
function alttimer(){
    if(!active) //button is start
    {
        $(alt1color).attr("src", "red.png");
        intervalId = startTimer();
        $(alt1but).val("Stop");
    }
    else //button is stop
    {
        $(alt1but).val("Start");
        clearTimeout(intervalId);
        counter = 300;
        $(alt1color).attr("src", "green.png");
        $('#alt1tim').attr("value", "");
}};

function startTimer() {
    return setTimeout(function(){
        if(t1 == '0')
        {
            $(alt1color).attr('src', 'green.png');
            $('#alt21im').attr('value', '');
            counter = 300;
        }
        else
        {
            counter--;
            $('#alt1tim').attr('value', counter);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Try something like that. I didn' test the code, but should work.

BTW, you don't have to create functions as strings.

Good luck